# oracle sql find top level part in multilevel structure

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I would like to ask you to help me to find top level id from multilevel structure.

my code is:

```
SELECT level,id_component, CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_part
  FROM structure
   START WITH id_component = '123'
CONNECT BY PRIOR id_part = id_component
```

this give me result like:

```
level id_component id_part
----- ------------ -------
1         123        770
2         770        771
3         771        778
3         771        880
```

but I need only two id_part from `level 3` (`778` and `880`)

many thanks

Comment: There is no way the query you posted gives you the result you posted. You start with `id_component = '123456'`, I don't see that in the output. Also, the query includes `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` in the `SELECT` clause - where is that column in the output? How can we take you seriously?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the mistake, I have changed.

Comment: did you notice the Answer already posted? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
```

right after the `FROM` clause and before `CONNECT BY`.